# Selenium Grid Hub and Node setup with Cucumber and Java

Tags: selenium-webdriver, cucumber-java

I am using Selenum with Cucumber and Java for my bdd frame work. I need to implement the Selenium Grid Hub and Node setup.Here is my driver initialization code.

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", driversBasePath+"\\chromedriver.exe");
Map<String, Object> prefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefs);
dr = new ChromeDriver(options);
NgWebDriver ngWebDriver = new NgWebDriver((JavascriptExecutor) dr);
ngWebDriver.waitForAngularRequestsToFinish();
ac = new Actions(dr);
wdw = new WebDriverWait(dr,30);
js = (JavascriptExecutor) dr;   
dr.get("www.google.com");
```

My hub URL is http://192.234.51.62:4444/wd/hub.

Comment: So what is the problem or error?

Comment: I would like to know how to implement the Selenium Grid Hub and Node setup with Cucumber and java. With serenity it is straight forward. We can use the command Webdriver.remote.url="http://192.234.51:4444/wd/hub"

Comment: There is nothing specific to cucumber for Selenium Grid Hub and Node setup. You should update question title and tags.